# The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found. Netcore Linux

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
 ❯ dotnet ef   
A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/home/ru/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/6.0.2/dotnet-ef/6.0.2/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/usr/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet].

The .NET runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=arch-x64&apphost_version=6.0.2

~
```

**dotnet ef not working**
After running the command is not working so what can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by adding this in whatever part of shell profile (it can be at the end):

```
# Netcore
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT
```

Your shell profile can be in one of these files:

- Bash Shell: ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc
- Korn Shell: ~/.kshrc or .profile
- Z Shell: ~/.zshrc or .zprofile

**Don't forget to use the command `source ~/.bashrc` (depending on your shell profile) for e.g, so env variables can load.**

[More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual)

To check if everything is ok run **dotnet ef**, you should get something like this:

```
❯ dotnet ef

                     _/\__       
               ---==/    \\      
         ___  ___   |.    \|\    
        | __|| __|  |  )   \\\   
        | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\ 
        |___||_|       /   \\\/\\

Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.2

Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]

Options:
  --version        Show version information
  -h|--help        Show help information
  -v|--verbose     Show verbose output.
  --no-color       Don't colorize output.
  --prefix-output  Prefix output with level.

Commands:
  database    Commands to manage the database.
  dbcontext   Commands to manage DbContext types.
  migrations  Commands to manage migrations.

Use "dotnet ef [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you aren't using snap, and you did the manual installation with the script. 
And maybe it can work with installations without snap and the script.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual

Answer (score 1):

I got this error (and many others) while using the [Snap version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap).
These problems all went away when I switched to the [package manager version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux).